# Can I use 'UIKeyboardTypeTwitter' as HTML input-type?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web, mobile-safari

In native iOS Apps you can use `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter` to display a keyboard that has `#` and `@` keys in default mode:
[image: Keyboard with UIKeyboardTypeTwitter]

Is there any way to have such a keyboard in Safari? 
[The Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008055-SW1) doesn't list it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[type="email"]` is close, but it adds a `.` next to the `@` button instead of a `#`

seems like a "tweet" type (or something more generically named) would be a useful addition to webkit, but I couldn't find any input types that trigger the `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter`

if there *is* an undocumented way to do it, mobile.twitter.com & m.facebook.com aren't using it:

[mobile safari: mobile.twitter.com new tweet keyboard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mvEg.png)

Seems like this would need escalated to a w3c request, although- Android doesn't appear to currently have a comparable keyboard mode.

Update: Filed as a webkit enhancement request: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156135

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get a `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter ` with Cordova?

Comment: @RobinLinus: never used it, but maybe something like this? https://github.com/mnill/cordova-custom-keyboard